# Can't select keyframes on timeline?

Tags: interface, keyframes

I opened up my project and everything was fine. But when I selected the keyframes, the yellow timeline thing would go over my keyframes?

[image]

[image]

How does this even work!?

Comment: What do you mean by "select"? You can't select keyframes on the timeline the way you can select them in the dopesheet or the graph editor.

Comment: I mean , You see the green Line , which you use to hover over keyframes quickly to change them? I cant go over them , the green line skips them and wont let me access them

Comment: Are the keyframes on an exact frame? (Could you add the same screenshots, but with the frame numbers?) What happens if you press the up or down arrow keys with your cursor in the timeline?

Comment: They go to the next frame after the one which has been inserted . Its really strange

Comment: That is quite strange, because you can use **Up / Down** Arrow key to switch among the keyframes in turn in Timeline. One suggestion: Timeline is a very simple thing for you to see time and keyframes, things can be controlled more flexably by using **Dopesheet** or **Graph Editor**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A keyframe does not have to be aligned to a rendered frame. While that may sound a bit un-intuitive, a frame is a point in time, for example 24 frames in a second. A keyframe can define a value at any point in time not just on a specific frame.

It is normally considered better to have keyframes aligned to frames to get cleaner animation results. To help with this the Dopesheet and Graph Editors can auto-snap when editing keyframes.

[image]

Having keyframes that aren't aligned to a frame means you moved the keyframes in the Dopesheet or Graph editor with snapping turned off. You can simply enable snapping and align them, if you enable snapping to nearest frame then select all the keyframes and start moving a little bit they will all snap to the nearest frame without destroying your animation.